# Converting list to data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a large list received after reading 20 images.

`p` is a large list(20 elements 4.6MB). Each element of list `p` represents a three-dimensional numeric array (`[1:100, 1:100, 1:3]`).

I am trying to convert the list in such a way such that each of the 20 elements is in its own row, and everything else is in columns (30000 columns). I have used `t.data.frame(p)` and list_`vect2df(p)` But neither of them is working to produce the required output.

Comment: have you tried as.dataframe(p)

Comment: yes...doesnt get me the required output

Comment: try binding each element of list into dataframe rowwise using rbind and for loop

Answer (score 0):

`c()` converts a dimensioned object to a simple vector. `do.call(rbind(...))` pastes elements of lists as the rows of a data frame. How about

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(big_list,c))
```

?

Comment: Even this did not give an output to the requirement. As a workaround, I resized and reshaped my image to a 1d array rather than 3d and just applied `(t(as.data.frame()))` .